# Proguard seems to have not effect / not to run when exporting Android app in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

I am about to release an Android app and would like to use Proguard to obfuscate the code. I did everything as described in [Googles Proguard Guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) but Proguard seems not to run:

This is what I did:

1. The guide says, that a *"proguard.cfg file is automatically generated in the root directory of the project"* There is no such file in my project-root but a `proguard-project.txt`file. I assume that this is the confic file the guide is talking about.
2. I made no changes to the `proguard-project.txt`file. Thus Proguard should apply to all class names, etc.
3. I edited the `project.properties` and uncommented the `proguard.config=...` line:

   `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt`

According to the guide this should be all that is necessary to configure Proguard. All that is not necessary to run Proguard is to build the app in `Release mode`.

I don't know how to munally run the app in `Release mode` but as the guide says this is done automatically when the app is build using the 'File/Export/Export Android Application` menu.

So, I exported the app to create the APK. The guid says that Proguard creates several files and folders in the project dir everytime it runs, e.g. `dump.txt`, `mapping.txt`, etc. But none of these files is created. Additionally there is no output in the consosole or the log. Thus I assume that Proguard did not run.

Is there a (easy) way to test if the file was obfuscated / if Proguard did run? What else to I have to do, to make Proguard work?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing all the right things. When you export, are you using your own key? Does the Eclipse Error log show anything? Is an .apk file actually exported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the default version of proguard-project.txt does nothing. It may be something like:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html
#
# Add any project specific keep options here:
#
# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

First of all try to add something to this file to check if the project compilation time changes. For example:

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
-dontpreverify
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Signature
# Obfuscation
-repackageclasses ''
-flattenpackagehierarchy ''
```

You could also check running `apktool decode YOUR_APK` that your classes and methods are renamed

I hope this help you!

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought "activating" Proguard by specifying the path to the `proguard-project.txt` would be sufficient to enable a basic obfuscation but this is not true. Without specifying further details in the `proguard-project.txt` Proguard does nothing at all. Thanks for the hint :-)

Answer (score 1):

That quite simple, first you create a file name proguard.cfg in the root folder of the project and define the rule, this is common rule: http://pastebin.com/N8GxdvAW
Add this line to project.properties

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

And choose Android Tool > Export sign application package, create key store and see the result. if you use any special libs you need to define your own rule if Eclipse failed to create sign apk, see proguard manual may help.

If it can create a signed apk you can see mapping.txt in proguard folder for any obfuscated class/constant